# Using dynamic onClick with ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Passing a dynamic property of *onClick= do something* by the use of `ref` gives me back: `TypeError: _this.listReference is null` listReference is defined in one of my components that i will show below.

**In Component #1**

```
class Component1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){   
        super(props)
        this.listReference= null;
}
//Returns
<div>
 <SomeComponent  list={(ref) => this.listReference= ref} />
 <Component2  onMarkerClick = {(index) => {
                    this.listReference.scrollTop = 48 * index
                                  }}/>
```

**In Component #2**

```
render() {
const {classes, driversStore, onMarkerCLick} = this.props

...

{driversStore.sortedSelectedOrders.map((order , index) => {
            return (
              <Component3
                onClick={ () => onMarkerClick(index)} />
```

**In Component #3**

```
  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        onClick={onClick}>
```

I expect upon click to trigger the scroll functionality (as Stated in Component #1).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget doing this.listReference = React.createRef(); in your constructor and referring it somewhere in your component as return <div ref={this.listReference} />;  ?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: @G_S I have  refered it. (forgot to include it in the code) ill edit my code so you can check again. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Check this example. Hope it can help you!**

```js
const Component2 = (props) =>(
  <button onClick={props.onClick}>click me</button>
);

const SomeCompo = (props) =>(
  <div>SomeComponent</div>
);

class Component1 extends React.Component{
    listReference = React.createRef();
  
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <SomeCompo list={this.listReference}>reference</SomeCompo>
          <Component2 onClick={this.handleClick} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    handleClick = () => {
    
      if(this.listReference){
       this.listReference={scrollTop:100};
      }
      console.log(this.listReference)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component1/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You should do the following in constructor,

`this.listReference = React.createRef()`

Comment: Hey. I tried `this.listReference = {}`  in return the console doesnt respond when i click. so its being rendered as empty

Comment: Check the example if it can help you!

Comment: Thanks alot for your Support!